# My EEEPc 900HA won't turn on/boot. Can it be fixed or does it need to be sent in?

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, bios, eee-pc

My EEEPc 900HA stopped booting up out of nowhere. It went to sleep and when I went to wake it up, it wouldn't wake up. I powered down and went to power back up, but no go. The power light comes on solid and the battery/corded power light blinks consistently. There is no HDD activity or light activity. No BIOS. Just the lights described.

I've troubleshooted the RAM, HDD, and internal power connections and everything checked out both on battery power and corded power. I've also reset the CMOS to no avail.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed it!

If you have this problem. Remove the RAM cover and remove the RAM (at least for the 900HA). There should be a gold sticker with BIOS information on it. Remove this sticker and touch something metal (I used a paper clip) to the two gold arrow heads. Replace the sticker, RAM and cover. You should be in business.

http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?pid=639681#p639681

Comment: This exact fix solved my problem. My EeePC 900HA wouldn't boot up. The hard drive light would flash for a second, then turn off. Nothing showed up on the screen. I used a small strand of solder wire to connect the BIOS arrows for a few seconds. I tried without the battery first, it didn't help. I tried again with the battery installed (bad idea I know) but it worked! My 5+ year-old EeePC 900HA is alive again!

Answer (score 1):

Could you take the battery out and connect it directly to supply and check if it comes on?

Comment: I've tried all power combinations. Same result.

Comment: probably mobo problem, is it under warranty? better let the company people have a look.